# How to alert json data in jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I have a **json** data like this in **jQuery**

```
{"res":"123","pgm":"bar","digit":"demo"}
```

Now I have to alert the `res` and `pgm`.

How i retrieve these two from the **json** data

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a JSON string or an object? You probably need to show the context to solve your *actual* problem.

Comment: alert(response.res) gives undefined

Comment: As I said, you need to give context, i.e. where do you get the data, what does it look like... We can't know why it would give undefined if you don't show your code.

Answer (score 2):

Do it like:

```
var data = {"res":"123","pgm":"bar","digit":"demo"};

alert(data.res);

alert(data.pgm);
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zb1zjpnm/1/)

[Nice tutorial about accessing JSON data.](http://www.mkyong.com/javascript/how-to-access-json-object-in-javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var json = {"res":"123","pgm":"bar","digit":"demo"};

alert(json.res+" - "+json.pgm);
```